# Template parse errors: Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag

Tags: angular

Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "div". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.

Comment: Why don't you just create a separate html file for this component and avoid this error-prone way of writing HTML code? You will spot the problem really quick that way.

Comment: when use template use the commas ` ` , so you needn't use + and can use the commillas `"` and `'` in your code

Comment: This is pretty tough to read, I would recommend moving all the logic into a method in your component class that does the heavy lifting and keep the template clean.

Comment: `` should be used when string spans multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the string concatenation rather use multi-line template literal of ES6.Refer [this](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/template-strings/)